# How to get a date range from a list of fromdate & todate to compare with another date

Tags: c#, validation, datetime

I have a collection of dates as below,

```
var dateList = new List<DatePrev>
{
    new DatePrev{ FromDate=new DateTime(2014,10,1), ToDate=new DateTime(2015,3,1)},
    new DatePrev{ FromDate=new DateTime(2013,2,1), ToDate=new DateTime(2013,10,1)},
    new DatePrev{ FromDate=new DateTime(2010,2,1), ToDate=new DateTime(2011,10,1)}
};
```

This list serves as a lookup list. 
I have a search data as below,

```
var newDate = new DatePrev { FromDate = new DateTime(2015, 2, 1), ToDate = new DateTime(2017, 5, 1) };
```

I want to search inside the dateList collection to find out whether the supplied newdate can be inserted inside dateList with proper date range.
as the supplied date list's from date is earlier to the todate of the first row of datelist, it should not allow to insert.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're asking. Do you want to add the new date range only if it doesn't overlap with any of the existing ranges?

Comment: yes. Sorry for in complete question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, what you're looking for is a way to check if two "date-spans" overlap.

I, myself, recently had such a problem, and the solution was rather easy.

Given two dates defined as:

- Date A with `Astart` and `Aend`
- Date B with `Bstart` and `Bend`

you can determine if they overlap if:
`!(Aend < Bstart || Astart > Bend)`

As such, you can write the following code:

```
class DatePrev
{
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }

    public static bool Overlap(DatePrev dateA, DatePrev dateB)
    {
        return !(dateA.ToDate < dateB.FromDate || dateA.FromDate > dateB.ToDate);
    }
}

(...)

        var newDate = new DatePrev(); //specify from and to

        if (!dateList.Any(d => DatePrev.Overlap(d, newDate)))
            dateList.Add(newDate);
```

The code assumes that a `DatePrev` contains "sane" values - i.e. `ToDate > FromDate`. Also, you may want to tweak the condition depending on if you treat the from / end dates as inclusive or exclusive (changing `< or >` to `<= or =>` where needed).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to add `newDate` to the existing list only if the date ranges already added do not overlap with the new one, you could do this:

```
 bool slotTaken = dateList.Any(x => (x.FromDate <= newDate.FromDate &&
                                     x.ToDate >= newDate.FromDate) ||
                                    (x.x.FromDate <= newDate.ToDate &&
                                     x.ToDate >= newDate.ToDate);

 if (!slotTaken) 
 {
     dateList.Add(newDate);
 }
```

Please note that the comparison condition could change depending on your requirements with respect to the cases in which the range ends are equal. The current solution rejects the new interval if either `newDate.FromDate` or `newDate.ToDate` are equal to the dates stored. That means, based on your example, that `new DatePrev { FromDate = new DateTime(2015, 3, 1), ToDate = new DateTime(2017, 5, 1) };` would get rejected. If equal dates are allowed, you can simply remove the `=` in the comparison but then you need to take into account the special case where both end dates are equal (i.e. the date range has been already added).